# How to use configuration settings in groups?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, application-settings

I develop a Windows desktop console application in C#.

I like to save some user configurations in groups or sections. Here is an example:

```
[Email Peter]  
UserName=Peter  
POP=mail.server1.com  
SMTP=smtp.server1.com  

[Email Paul]  
UserName=Paul  
POP=mail.hotmail.com  
SMTP=smtp.hotmail.com
```

I looked at Project, Properties, Settings and there are only names and values, no sections or groups.
And I looked at the ConfigurationManager Class, and there are also no sections or groups - at least I didn't see them.
I am sure many people have similar requirements but I can’t find a built in solution.
Sure, I can write these values in a text file like an ini file but I guess that is not the recommended way to do this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A small addition: The above sample with email settings is just an easy understandable example. In reality I want to save other information about different file types, search patterns and other settings. But they are all in groups like 5 different file types with each 4 settings.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem very good idea to store this kind of data in project's settings. I would add userSettings.xml file instead (if you cannot store this data in database). This would allow you to set your data in "groups" as you wish. For example:

`<userSettings>
    <user id="Peter">
        <UserName>Peter</UserName>
        <POP>mail.server1.com</POP>
        <SMTP>smtp.server1.com</SMTP>
    </user>
    <user id="Paul">
        <UserName>Paul</UserName>
        <POP>mail.hotmail.com</POP>
        <SMTP>smtp.hotmail.com</SMTP>
    </user>
</userSettings>`

Comment: XPath: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or XMLReader: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58239-c-tutorial-reading-and-writing-xml-files/